# Pass one parameter in a Tornado HttpGet with several parameters

Tags: python, android, http-post, tornado, http-get

I want pass one parameter in a Url (to update one of many paramaters contained by my URL) like this:

```
httpGet.setURI(new URI(url/user?"nickname"="John")
```

ServerSide in Python:

```
class GetInfo(BaseHandler):
  def Get(self):
        nickname = self.get_argument("nickname")
        gender = self.get_argument("gender")
        logging.info(nickname)
        logging.info(gender)

  application = tornado.web.Application([
  (r"/", MainHandler),
  (r"/user", GetInfo),
  ])
```

The server told me that I can't do this because the parameter "gender" is missing.
How can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Do you see any request from the log on the server side? Do you test from the emulator or a real device?

Comment: Android Emulator connected in local to my Tornado WebServer. I've just seen the error of "missing parameter "nickname" " on server side. 
Normally, can I pass one parameter like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>First your URI seems to be wrong.</strike>

```
httpGet.setURI(new URI(url + "/user?nickname=John")
```

And if you test from emulator to webserver and you use both on the same machine, use the IP address of the server instead of something like `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Example:

```
String url = "http://192.168.1.104";
httpGet.setURI(new URI(url + "/user?nickname=John");
```

**Edit:**
The answer to this OP is below:

it seems from the example at tornadoweb.org/documentation  that you can set a default value. So you can try something like `gender = self.get_argument("gender",None)` . So gender should be set to `None` if you dont pass any `gender` parameter in the query string

Comment: Of course, I passed my url like this:
httpGet.setURI(new URI(192.168.0.1:8888/user?"nickname"="John")

Comment: In my opinion, I can't pass one parameter with an URL whitch ask two. Maybe be can you confirm?

Comment: Yes you can, on the server side, they will be an error though when evaluating the 2nd parameter. I just re-read your OP and you can add new parameters to url with `&` like `httpGet.setURI(new URI(url + "/user?nickname=John&gender=M")`

Comment: Yes, it's the point! If I don't want to pass the second, I just want to update the first. Is it possible or I have to declare an other handler with an other url?

Comment: I dont know much about Python and Tornado but it seems from the example at http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation that you can set a default value. So you can try something like `gender = self.get_argument("gender",None)` . So gender should be set to None if you dont pass any `gender` parameter in the query string

Comment: Thanks! it sould be that! I'll try as soon as possible.